# when make using clang compile php7, got a error 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:' ; 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1'

Tags: php, makefile, compiler-errors, clang, symbols

make on OS X 10.12 Sierra

I want compile PHP 7 on machine, I can do it on linux/FreeBSD, but I can't do it on OS X. and I don't use virtual machine. It spend power to quick. If it can solve I will do it on vm.

PHP 7.0.11

command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd2.4/bin/apxs
```

error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__tsrm_ls_cache", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
"_executor_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__tsrm_ls_cache", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
  _php_apache_server_startup in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_ub_write in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_flush in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_get_stat in sapi_apache2.o
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  "_core_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_apache_server_startup in sapi_apache2.o
  "_executor_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
  _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_ini_dtor in sapi_apache2.o
  "_sapi_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_ub_write in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_flush in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_get_stat in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_getenv in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_header_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_sapi_send_headers in sapi_apache2.o
  ...
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  "_ts_allocate_id", referenced from:
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__tsrm_ls_cache", referenced from:
  _zm_startup_apache in php_functions.o
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
  "_ts_resource_ex", referenced from:
  "_executor_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_apache_server_startup in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
  "_tsrm_get_ls_cache", referenced from:
  _php_apache_server_startup in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
  "_tsrm_shutdown", referenced from:
  _php_apache_server_shutdown in sapi_apache2.o
  _php_apache_child_shutdown in sapi_apache2.o
  "_tsrm_startup", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  _php_apache_server_startup in sapi_apache2.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp7.bundle] Error 1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__tsrm_ls_cache", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
  "_executor_globals_id", referenced from:
  _php_print_info in info.o
  _php_print_gpcse_array in info.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/phpdbg/phpdbg] Error 1
```

this error when I compile php on clang. Maybe it source code error and someone can report to PHP community?

clang version

```
cc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

here is clang version

Comment: Not certain about Sierra (I am refraining from upgrading until i push my current project, every OSX update has broken my pipeline so far). However, when it comes to OSX, for every version prior to Sierra, i have used **[homebrew](http://brew.sh/)** as package manager. They currently have php7.0 and php7.1 available. If you brew, dont forget to set `/usr/local/bin` as top dog on your path.

Comment: Possible related https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77996&edit=1